# delete a line from a file containing the exact number and quit on the first find & delete

Tags: sed, text-files, exact-match

I am trying to delete a numerical value once only from a file where there could be more than one instance of that value.
file_input=

```
2  
4  
18  
8  
8  
10  
12  
14
```

I need to delete '8' but only once and i want to keep '18'. The final result should be in file_output as such:

```
2  
4  
18  
8  
10  
12  
14
```

I tried `sed '/8/d'`, `grep -v -w '8'` and `awk '$1 !=8'` but they all delete 8, 8, and 18.

Comment: How to replace '8' by a var such as $number as this function can be called to delete a different number when used?

Comment: With a variable: `n="8"; sed '1,/^'"$n"'$/{/^'"$n"'$/d}' file`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest with GNU sed:

```
sed '1,/^8$/{/^8$/d}' file
```

Output:

```
2
4
8
10
12
14
```

From first line to line which contains only `8` (`1,/^8$/`) delete line which contains only `8` (`/^8$/d`).

---

See: `man sed` and [The Stack Overflow Regular Expressions FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22944075/3776858)

Comment: This works as I want even if I add 88 before the value 8. Wonderful, thanks.

Comment: When you have to write the same code multiple times (e.g. `/^8$/` twice in this case), it means you should look for a different solution.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the `awk` version

```
$ awk '!($1==8 && !c++)' ip.txt
2  
4  
18  
8  
10  
12  
14
```

- `$1==8 && !c++` check if first field is exactly `8`, if so check whether `c` evaluates to false(`c` will get incremented and so won't be false next time)

  - we don't want to print when this is true, hence the outer negation
- this will work even if there are whitespaces around the first field, like in the given sample in question

Comment: Ahem - double negative? `awk '$1==8 && !c++{next} 1' ip.txt`